# I'm not able to run a class file on the command line even though there are no problems with Java installation and path variables settings

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I've been using Eclipse to practice programming Java for a while. Haven't got any problems so far, but today I just wanted to compile and run my code on the command line (I'm using Windows OS) and it's not working.

Suppose the compiled file name is 'Test.class'. After compiling, when I put 'java Test' on the command line then error message says, "couldn't find or load main class Test"

But I have set all the system variables like %JAVA_HOME%, Path, CLASSPATH and had no problems running that code on Eclipse.

Below are screenshots of my setting information on the command line. (Please ignore the Korean words)

**system variables**
[image: system variables]

**when I entered 'java' on the command line**
[image: when I entered 'java' on the command line]

**when I entered 'javac' on the command line**
[image: when I entered 'javac' on the command line]

**checking java version**
[image: checking java version]

No Problems, Right? But the error occurred, when I entered 'java Test' to run this code after compiling Test.java to Test.class (The letters you can't understand is Korean, ignore it, it says "couldn't find or load main class Test")
[image: Error, when I entered 'java Test' after compiling Test.java to Test.class]

Help me Please!

**------------------Below is additional screenshot-----------------------**
...
Can you see? I compiled TestClass.java and converted it into TestClass.class but when I executed "java TestClass", the error appears.
[image]

Below is my code..... I did almost nothing on the code, just wanted to test command line method....

**TestClass.java**

```
package test;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("SOS");
    }

}
```

Comment: this `javac`/ `java` operation only succeeds if your`Test` class has default package.

Comment: Thanks for replying! But javac / java operation works without any classes. What do you mean if my class has default package?

Comment: Meaning, you don't have a `package` statement. Basically, you should show us your code...

Comment: @TITTO your `Test.java` most likely has a package statement (right?). Your compilation is fine and generates a `Test.class` (verify this). But you can't run it like you do since `java Test` expects to find a `Test` class in the default package.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've just updated my question including my code and another screenshot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `CLASSPATH` environment variable. It exists, but doesn't include the current directory.

Unless you really *need* the `CLASSPATH` environment variable for some reason, I would remove it - then it will default to just the current directory. All the framework classes are already on the boot classpath - you don't need to worry about those.

If for some reason you can't change your environment variables, just specify the classpath on the command line:

```
java -cp . TestClass
```

Comment: It still didn't work even though I removed CLASSPATH variable and specified the classpath on the command line. I think something's wrong with my computer. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: @TITTO: If you changed your environment variable, you'd need to restart the command prompt for that to take effect. But if `java -cp . TestClass` doesn't work, that's a different matter...